# prototype conflict request file named functions in prototype

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have site with prototype included in the pages, also i have a third party script that uses jquery. when page loading, console log showing more than 10 errors like below:

```
function eachSlice(number, iterator, context) {    
  var index = -number
  , slices = []
  ,array = this.toArray();
  if (number < 1) 
    return array;    
  while ((index += number) < array.length)      
    slices.push(array.slice(index, index+number));    
  return slices.collect(iterator, context);  
}
```

when i look into prototype script, i saw the `eachSlice` inside it.

by the way here is  the 3rd party script http://pastebin.com/sDXE3crb

what causing this error?

an image might talk better than thousand words.
[image]

Comment: please let me know what makes you down vote my question?

Comment: Please include a minimal example that reproduces the problem, a clear problem statement, and any error messages or other information to help identify the problem. Without this information, it is hard to answer the question.

Comment: What javascript source file is causing this log or error?

Comment: @bjb568 there is no error at all, everytime i open the page there is GET request log, page trying to load a files that is not in the server. like i said before it was requesting http://example.com/function%20PROTOTYPE_FUNCTIONS_NAME(){blablabla..}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically a failed xhr request is an error. The errors are in smc.js at line 29

Because you're using prototype.js and prototype.js is modifying core JavaScript objects the following would cause that error (in smc.js):

```
    for (pn in d) {
        p.push(pn + "=" + encodeURIComponent(d[pn]));
    };
```

you can change that to:

```
    for (pn in d) {
      if(Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty
          .call(d,pn)){
        p.push(pn + "=" + encodeURIComponent(d[pn]));
      }
    };
```

That would take care of this error and unneeded requests to the server.

Later at line 97 in your pastebin there is another for loop that can cause problems:

```
    for (var i in ims) {
        d += '<img src...
    };
```

Maybe you should make sure it doesn't do that for members added by prototype.js as well:

```
    for (var i in ims) {
      if(Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty
          .call(ims,i)){
        d += '<img src...
      }
    };
```

Comment: thank you, i will try to make modifications as you suggested.